# If the user enter "q", program quits

Tags: c++

I have this C++ code and I am trying to do the following:

Prompt the user to enter "p" to play or "q" to quit, if the user enters anything "p" the program will continue, if the user enters "q" program would just terminate and if they entered an invalid input, it would also terminate. How do I do that?.

Thank you,

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int Umain = 0;
double Atemp = 0;
double Utemp = 0;
double Working = 0;
double Total = 0;
char Answer = 'x';

void displayOverview ();

void playOrQuit();    

void promptNumber();

int main(){

    displayOverview();

    playOrQuit();

    promptNumber();

    return 0;
}

void displayOverview(){


}

void playOrQuit(){

    string playOrNot;

    cout << "If you want to play please press 'p' for play, and 'q' if you wish to quit\n";
    cin >> playOrNot;

    if(playOrNot == "p"){
        cout << "Awesome, lets start playing !!! \n";

    }if(playOrNot == "q"){
        cout << "Alright then, see you soon !!\n";

    }
}


void promptNumber(){

    do{
    cout << "Please Enter numbers between 1 and 12: ";
    cin >> Umain;
    cout << "\n";
        for (Utemp = Umain; Utemp > 0; Utemp--)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a number: ";
            cin >> Atemp;
            Working = (Working + Atemp);
        }
    }while (Answer == 'y');
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Please don't tag your questions in the title - that's what the actual tags are for

Comment: @NathanOliver How do I do it?

Comment: if `void playOrQuit();` was `bool playOrQuit();` you could `if (!playOrQuit()) { return 0; }`. You're going to want t loop in main or the whole idea is moot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a call to `exit` after you detect 'q' was pressed:

```
}if(playOrNot == "q"){
    cout << "Alright then, see you soon !!\n";
    exit(0); // <=== Add this here
```

Exiting with a `0` traditionally means the program exited in an expected fashion and without any errors.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to do this kind of thing is to have `PlayOrQuit` return a `bool` with `true` meaning "keep on playing" and `false` meaning "quit". Use that function to control a loop:

```
while (PlayOrQuit()) {
    // game logic goes here
}
```

That way you can put any appropriate cleanup code after the game loop instead of having a brute-force exit from down inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can achieve this.
But I suggest you include the stdlib.h library and use system("exit") right inside your else statements that is meant to exit the program.

Comment: `system("exit")` is quite a bit heavier in weight than you want or need and lacks portability. It is starting another process to call the exit ms-dos command which will end the program with all the subtlety if a headsman's axe.

Answer (score 0):

Add end(), return 0 or exit(0).
Use u brain like, if you need this then i will remember nearest possible thing you spot from past.

So you never made these kind of mistake.

```
}if(playOrNot == "q"){
    cout << "Alright then, see you soon !!\n";
    exit(0);
}
```